# The Facebook Autopost module "user hasn't authorized the application"

Tags: social-network

I have a problem with the [Facebook Autopost](https://www.drupal.org/project/fb_autopost) module for Drupal 7.28): After publishing a node, I get an authorization error.

> Facebook SDK threw an error: OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't
>   authorized the application to perform this action

I have checked permissions "*Publish Actions*", "*Publish Stream*", "*Manage Pages*" for Administrator role in *fbpermissions* module.

Also, I have submitted "manage_pages" in my app but cannot submit "publish_actions" because of this:

> It looks like you haven't made any API requests to access content with
>   the publish_actions permission in the last 30 days.

Don't know what to do now. Have no idea why it's not working and what Facebook app permissions are missing. Was googling it for an about 2 hours. Checked all found solutions... none of them worked...

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you add any user to roles section and if the user haven't accepted the role and you are trying to post something on his behalf. first accept the role in developers page of Facebook.